# URL rewrite using Apache

Tags: apache, copy-paste, redirect

I have an application hosted in Apache
http://www.example.com

The DocumentRoot is set as /var/www/html/myapp

Now, I want to write a rule, such that, if someone triggers the URL http://www.example.com/abc, it should redirect to http://www.example.com

The tricky part is, this redirection should happen only if user directly copy-paste http://www.example.com/abc or refresh the browser when the user is in http://www.example.com/abc

"abc" can be any string.

Comment: mod_rewrite doesn't know about user actions like copy paste or refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with the following addition to httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com

     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc

     <Directory /var/www/html/abc>
         RewriteEngine on

         # Don't rewrite files or directories
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
         RewriteRule ^ - [L]

         # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
         RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```